# Insert numbers into a column PSQL

Tags: sql, database, psql

I have a table called Nums in which I have just one column called text. I need to create a PSQL query that will insert a row for each number between 100000 and 199999.

```
Row number is 100000
Row number is 100001
Row number is 100002
...
Row number is 199999
```

Obviously, if the range was smaller and only 10 numbers, it could be done with 10 simple insert statements, but this is not the case. I'm new to PSQL and want to know how this could be achived? Is a sort of loop needed?

Comment: Why do you want to store a list of numbers in a table? I think you have an X/Y Problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive queries.

```
with recursive cte as
(
  select 100000 as n
  union all
  select   n + 1
  from     cte 
  where    n < 199999 
)
select  * from cte;
```

Try this [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/03380/20)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "Postgres" for the database, use `generate_series()`:

```
insert into nums (text)
    select n
    from generate_series(100000, 199999, 1) gs(n);
```

Postgres will automatically convert `n` to a string -- although it seems unusual to store numbers as strings.  You can also be explicit using `select n::text`.

EDIT:

If you need the full string, it would just look like:

```
insert into nums (text)
    select 'Row number is ' || (n::text)
    from generate_series(100000, 199999, 1) gs(n);
```

Comment: I don't need to convert the number to string but have the literal value of the row to be something alone the lines of "Row number is 100000". Would I just replace gs(n) with gs("Row number is" + n);